# Tkinter bind only works once

Tags: python, tkinter

I cannot find any reason that this bind isn't working. I have tried setting focus, moving the bind outside of the class, among other things. The strange thing is it works once at the beginning of the program. This leads me to believe that the bind does work but not as intended.

```
import tkinter as tk
import os
import Themes

##########################################################################
root = tk.Tk()

topleft = tk.Frame(root,
               bg = 'red',
               )

topmid = tk.Frame(root,
              bg = 'white',
              )

topright = tk.Frame(root,
                bg = 'blue',
                )

bottomleft = tk.Frame(root,
                  bg = 'yellow',
                  )

bottommid = tk.Frame(root,
                  bg = 'green',
                  )

bottomright = tk.Frame(root,
                    bg = 'black',
                    )

tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight = 20)
tk.Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight = 30)
topleft.grid(row = 0, column = 0,
         sticky = tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W,
         rowspan = 2, columnspan = 1)

tk.Grid.columnconfigure(root, 1, weight = 20)
topmid.grid(row = 0, column = 1,
        sticky = tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W,
        rowspan = 1, columnspan = 2)

tk.Grid.columnconfigure(root, 3, weight = 85)
topright.grid(row = 0, column = 3,
          sticky = tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W,
          rowspan = 3, columnspan = 1)

tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, 2, weight = 40)
bottomleft.grid_propagate(False)
bottomleft.grid(row = 2, column = 0,
            sticky = tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W,
            rowspan = 1, columnspan = 3)

tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, 1, weight = 10)
tk.Grid.columnconfigure(root, 1, weight = 10)
bottommid.grid(row = 1, column = 1,
           sticky = tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W,
           rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1)

tk.Grid.rowconfigure(root, 1, weight = 10)
tk.Grid.columnconfigure(root, 2, weight = 10)
bottomright.grid(row = 1, column = 2,
             sticky = tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W,
             rowspan = 1, columnspan = 1)
##########################################################################

class File_selector:
    def __init__(self):
    self.scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(bottomleft,
                                  orient = 'vertical'
                                  )
    self.listbox = tk.Listbox(bottomleft,
                              yscrollcommand = self.scrollbar.set
                              )
    self.check = print(self.listbox.curselection())

    self.scrollbar['command'] = self.listbox.yview

    for file in os.listdir(os.curdir):
        if file.endswith(".py"):
            self.listbox.insert(tk.END, file)

    self.listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', lambda e: self.check)

    self.grid()
    def grid(self):      
    self.scrollbar.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = tk.N+tk.S)

    tk.Grid.rowconfigure(bottomleft, 0, weight = 1)
    tk.Grid.columnconfigure(bottomleft, 0, weight = 1)
    self.listbox.grid(row = 0, column = 0,
                      sticky = tk.N+tk.E+tk.S+tk.W)

File_selector()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: that triggers once on any select ... you then need to get the selected item ...

Comment: Doesn't `self.check` do that? For the moment i'm just trying to get the program to acknowledge me clicking the listbox. @Joran

Comment: The indentation on your example is messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line

```
self.check = print(self.listbox.curselection())
```

is incorrect.

It runs `print()` and prints text on screen (when `File_selector` object is created) and then it assigns `None` to `self.check` (because `print()` returns `None`)

You need normal function

```
def check(self, event):
    print(self.listbox.curselection())
```

or `lambda` function

```
self.check = lambda event:print(self.listbox.curselection())
```

And then you can bind

```
self.listbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.check)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks a lot! For future is there anyway for me to check if anything is returning `None`?

Comment: Python functions return None by default.  Read the doc or the docstring or use `help(func)` to find out about non-default returns.